# How to suppress/disable "cache miss" messages when running rspec tests in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm starting to see the following output when running request rspec specs:

```
cache: [GET /login] miss
cache: [GET /javascripts/jquery.min.js?1317513028] miss
```

Normaly I would get green dots for passing tests and red Fs with some info for error messages.

Is there a way to disable the cache miss messages from the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with rspec and that rspec is just printing out what is in the rails log. I think this [post by Brian Weaver](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/msg/486c3a63d0a00e7f) on the Phusion Passenger discussion group might answer your question:

> Do you have rack-cache installed? I spent a good day+ tracing through Passenger/Rails/Rack and lots of other gems to find out why lines similar to that one was appearing. 
>   Add the following to your production.rb or development.rb file to get rid of the 'cache: ....' line
>
> config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {:metastore => "rails:/", :entitystore => "rails:/", :verbose => false}
>
> I pulled that line from within the "middleware" configuration of Rails an just changed the 'verbose' from true to false.

In your case, I guess you want to add it your your test environment file.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me either :( Wonder if there are other ways?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @RyanTM you also need to turn caching on for the test environment so that DragonFly does not configure its own Rack::Cache (with :verbose => true) but instead uses the one setup by Rails.

```
# set Rack::Cache verbose to false to prevent logging to rspec output         
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true                               
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {:metastore => "rails:/", :entitystore => "rails:/", :verbose => false}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get either of the above workarounds to work for me, but adding this to my **'config/initializers/dragonfly.rb'** worked:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  Rails.application.middleware.delete Rack::Cache
  Rails.application.middleware.insert 0, Rack::Cache, {
    :verbose     => false,
    :metastore   => URI.encode("file:#{Rails.root}/tmp/dragonfly/cache/meta"), # URI encoded in case of spaces
    :entitystore => URI.encode("file:#{Rails.root}/tmp/dragonfly/cache/body")
  }
end
```